# how to add extra variable in this getjson request?

Tags: ajax, json, variables

I want to add an extra variable like **new_var=2** in this get json request.after multiple efforts.I am unable to do it.Please Help

```
 jQuery.getJSON(serverFQDN + '/widget_submit.php?callback=?', {
        install_url: window.location.href
    }, serverResponse);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you can't to add extra parameter in the sending data object?

```
 jQuery.getJSON(serverFQDN + '/widget_submit.php?callback=?', {
    install_url: window.location.href,
    new_var:2
}, serverResponse);
```